# wso2 apim SOAP endpoint with username and password

Tags: web-services, soap, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I have wso2 apim 2.1 and I have request to connect to SOAP endpoint which is secured with username and password.
During add procedure of SOAP endpoint I dont have possibility to enter such credentials nor possiblity to use mediation(eg like for rest api) as I get not authorized before enetring next phase. is there a way how to do this without using ESB ?

how to connect to secured SOAP backend using just apim ?

or Do I have to use ESB and follow similar way as [LINK](http://xacmlinfo.org/2012/11/05/how-to-invoke-secured-backend-service-using-wso2-esb/)

thank you for any advice

Answer (score 0):

We were not able to parse the backend wsdl from some reason and we have done workaround  by donwloading wsdl and manualy pushing it to registry, after that we were able to follow next steps.